# Can I use htmlunit in a web service?

Tags: java, html, web-services, webserver, htmlunit

I've been trying to use htmlunit inside a web service function. I am new to web services and I used this tutorial for implementing a simple web service: http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/education/web/t320/Implementing_a_Simple_Web_Service.pdf

Then I tried to implement a web service that will get 3 strings as parameters, go to a web site using htmlunit, fill the forms in the site with the 3 strings and click on the search button, parse the result page and return a string containing information from the result page.  I went with the naive approach and tried to implement that web service using the same steps as the tutorial used. The steps were:

1. create a dynamic web project
2. add the htmlunit jar's into the build path.
3. implement the working junit test as a function and add to the project
4. create a web server and client using the web service wizard of eclipse.

After that, the wizard generated a simple interface with 3 textboxes and I entered the values that worked in the junit test project. But I got an exception that said:

```
Exception: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException Message: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

Since I am really new to web services did I make a horrible mistake when I thought the steps for simple web service in the tutorial would work for this or is this some error that can be fixed? In general can I actually use htmlunit in this way or is it completely impossible?

The code for the webserver is below:

```
package webService.test.TravelComparing;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.Writer;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;

public class TravelComparingTest {

public String homePage(String place, String checkinDate, String checkoutDate) throws Exception {
    final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

String URL = "http://hotels.travelcomparing.com/SearchResults.aspx?languageCode=EN&currencyCode=EUR&destination=place:" + place + "&radius=0km&checkin=" + checkinDate +"&checkout=" + checkoutDate + "&Rooms=1&adults_1=1&pageSize=15&pageIndex=0&sort=MinRate-asc&showSoldOut=false&view=hc_sr_summary&scroll=0&mapstate=contracted";

HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(URL);
webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(10000);
String htmlContent = page.asXml();
Writer out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
        new FileOutputStream("travelcomparing.html"), "UTF-8"));
    try {
        out.write(htmlContent);
    } finally {
        out.close();
    }

    String hotelName = "";
    String priceFrom = "";

    String result = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){

        int index1 = htmlContent.indexOf ( "<div fn=");
        int index2 = htmlContent.indexOf("<div fn=", index1 + 8);
        String row = (String) htmlContent.subSequence(index1 , index2);
        htmlContent = htmlContent.substring(index2);
        //System.out.println(row);

        int index3 = row.indexOf("class=\"hc_i_hotel\" p=\"2\">");
        int index4 = row.indexOf("</a>", index3);
        hotelName = (String) row.subSequence(index3 + 61, index4 -34);
        System.out.println(hotelName);
        result = result + hotelName + " ";

        int index5 = row.indexOf("<dd class=\"hc_i_price\">");
        int index6 = row.indexOf("</dd>", index5);
        String priceRow = (String) row.subSequence(index5, index6 + 5);

        int index7 = priceRow.indexOf("<span class=\"hc_pr_syb\">");
        int index8 = priceRow.indexOf("<span class=\"hc_pr_cur\">");
        priceFrom = (String) priceRow.subSequence(index7 + 148, index8 - 38);
        System.out.println(priceFrom);
        result = result + priceFrom + "    ";
    }
    return result;
}

}
```

EDIT:

the full contents of the tomcat console is below. The exception I mentioned is displayed in the result view of the client and I couldn't find it anywhere else.

```
May 20, 2013 7:17:15 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin/client;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/lib/i386;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.0\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\eclipse;;.
May 20, 2013 7:17:15 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:TravelComparingTest' did not find a matching property.
May 20, 2013 7:17:15 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:TravelComparingTestClient' did not find a matching property.
May 20, 2013 7:17:15 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:TravelComparing2' did not find a matching property.
May 20, 2013 7:17:15 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:TravelComparing2Client' did not find a matching property.
May 20, 2013 7:17:15 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:traveltest' did not find a matching property.
May 20, 2013 7:17:15 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:traveltestClient' did not find a matching property.
May 20, 2013 7:17:15 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
May 20, 2013 7:17:15 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
May 20, 2013 7:17:15 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 410 ms
May 20, 2013 7:17:15 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
May 20, 2013 7:17:15 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.40
May 20, 2013 7:17:16 AM org.apache.axis.utils.JavaUtils isAttachmentSupported
WARNING: Unable to find required classes (javax.activation.DataHandler and javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart). Attachment support is disabled.
May 20, 2013 7:17:17 AM org.apache.axis.utils.JavaUtils isAttachmentSupported
WARNING: Unable to find required classes (javax.activation.DataHandler and javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart). Attachment support is disabled.
May 20, 2013 7:17:17 AM org.apache.axis.utils.JavaUtils isAttachmentSupported
WARNING: Unable to find required classes (javax.activation.DataHandler and javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart). Attachment support is disabled.
May 20, 2013 7:17:17 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
May 20, 2013 7:17:17 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
May 20, 2013 7:17:17 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 2044 ms
May 20, 2013 7:17:19 AM org.apache.axis.utils.JavaUtils isAttachmentSupported
WARNING: Unable to find required classes (javax.activation.DataHandler and javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart). Attachment support is disabled.
```

Comment: Yes, you can use htmlunit for that, provided the machine which the web server (with the web service) will run has access to the internet (or that site, at least). Your exception seems too small, can you post the entire stack trace?

Comment: I'll add the entire stack trace to the question. By the way do you know if I can use selenium in the same way too? I'm not sure because of the firefox window popping up and all.

Comment: You can use selenium with htmlunit as its browser, instead of firefox. Firefox alone would open windows, as you predicted. There are ways to not make it open windows (like setting up a selenium remote server, or something), but its advanced stuff.

Comment: so do you have an idea about the cause of the exception?

Comment: Short answer, yes you can use it.

Comment: but can I use it in the steps I described in the question? Or am I missing a point and that's causing the exception? I will need a bit more than the short answer I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this issue by deleting the file writing code and surrounding all necessary fields with a try catch block. The reason this exception is thrown appears to be an io exception thrown in the function, but when reflect is used, it shows the exception in the question instead of an io exception.